# BeautifulSoup4 - AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.sherdog.com/fighter/1"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

links = soup.find_all("a")

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "module fight_history"})

for item in g_data:
 print item.contents[3].find_all(href=re.compile("/fighter")).text
```

There error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I have figured out that I can run each print line individually as such:

```
for item in g_data:
 print item.contents[3].find_all(href=re.compile("/fighter"))[0].text
 print item.contents[3].find_all(href=re.compile("/fighter"))[1].text
 print item.contents[3].find_all(href=re.compile("/fighter"))[2].text
 print item.contents[3].find_all(href=re.compile("/fighter"))[3].text
```

And this will output:

```
Tony Lopez
Joey Villasenor
Brian Sleeman
Reggie Cardiel
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong here.  What would be the most logical way to get the above output without having to count and repeat the same line over and over?

Comment: `print "\n".join([x.text for x in item.contents[3].find_all(href=re.compile("/fighter"))])`?

Answer (score 0):

`find_all()` returns list of elements and you have to use `text` with every element separately

```
elements = item.contents[3].find_all(href=re.compile("/fighter"))

for x in elements:
    print( x.text )
```